# How to skip tests that hangs/stuck during execution Selenium - Maven - Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to ask for your assistance regarding my issue. I have Regression Suite(.xml) that contains 50 test scripts. We are able to execute the regression suite in Jenkins using Maven, but it suddenly hangs/stuck. For example:

Test Case 1-15 are completed, but when in Test Case 16, the build/execution suddenly stuck/hangs on a certain step. I tried to execute the Test Case 16 in my Eclipse to know what step/code has the issue, but it's working fine.

I would like to ask if there is a maven-surefire functionality that when it detects that a test script is stuck/hangs for a certain number of minutes(for example 5 mins), it will fail that test script then proceed to the next one.

Kindly see below my pom.xml

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <source>1.8</source>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${xmlPath}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: How does it relates to #Selenium? Can you consider showing your work please? Do mention on which lines the execution hangs/stucks. Thanks

Comment: We use selenium to create and test our automated scripts. When we are executing our scripts in jenkins, we use maven. Actually, we cant see the exact line in the code because it hangs/stuck during execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a timeout to the test annotation in the test itself:

```
@Test(timeout=600000)  //Fails if the method takes longer than 10 minutes
```

It's in milliseconds so you just need to decide the maximum length of time the test should take and then [calculate it from there](https://www.google.com/search?q=10%20minutes%20to%20milliseconds&oq=10%20minutest%20to%20mill&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.4840j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)

EDIT: If you just want to set it once without having to add the timeout to each individual test then you can set a rule in the base class:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;

...

@Rule
public TestWatcher watcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {           
        if (description.getMethodName().toLowerCase().contains("thisTestTakesLonger")) {
            return new FailOnTimeout(base, 600000); //10 minutes = 600000
        } else {
            return new FailOnTimeout(base, 300000); //5 minutes = 300000
        }  
    }
};
```

The else is the global timeout, the if is if you have an individual test that takes longer (you may just want the bit in the else if every test is about the same length)

Comment: I think it's a good workaround. But is there other way wherein I will just update the POM then all the changes will be applied to all the scripts?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way in the POM but if it's to find a way of setting it just in one place then if your tests are descended from a base class you can set a global timeout there. I don't remember off hand how we did it(I think it was with a rule) but I'll check in the morning when I'm back at work and update the answer.

Comment: Okay. I'll wait for your answer. Thanks . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get maven to ignore test failure by setting this property to true in pom.xml

```
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

Comment: Seems OP is asking for a way to retrieve the executing `thread` when it is hung/stuck. Thanks